# VB.NET - "There is no row at position 0" but Records in Database

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, ado.net, dataset

Having a DataSet problem in VB.NET/Access.
Code should return 1 record and display the results on a form.

Basically when I step through the code in debug mode it returns 1 row and works fine, 
but when I run the code without breakpoints I get the error message:

> There is no row at position 0

VB.NET 2010 & MS Access 97

```
Dim sConnectionString As String = "dsn=MyDatabase"
Dim sSQL As String = ""
Dim DBConnection As New OdbcConnection(sConnectionString)

Dim dsMaster As New DataSet
Dim daMaster As New OdbcDataAdapter
Dim dtMaster As New DataTable

Try   
    DBConnection.Open()

    sSQL = "SELECT * FROM myTable"
    daMaster.SelectCommand = New OdbcCommand(sSQL, DBConnection)
    daMaster.Fill(dsMaster, "MasterDataSet")

    If dsMaster.Tables(0).Rows.Count <> 0 Then
       dtMaster = dsMaster.Tables(0)

       sItem1 = dtMaster.Rows(0).Item(0).ToString
       sItem2 = dtMaster.Rows(0).Item(1).ToString
       sItem3 = dtMaster.Rows(0).Item(2).ToString
    Else
       MessageBox.Show("No Records Available", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    End If
```

- When I run the code, I get the messagebox saying *No Records*.
- When I run in debug mode with a breakpoint on the **IF** statement, I get the messagebox saying *No Records*.
- When I run in debug mode with a breakpoint on the **FILL** statement, I get  1 record returned and the code in **IF** statement executes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your `daMaster.Fill` is filling a table called "MasterDataSet", try changing your If statement to check `dsMaster.Tables("MasterDataSet").Rows.Count`
Alternatively, remove the parameter from the Fill method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Logan, only saw your post now. I try that when I get a chance and let you know if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it:

```
Dim sConnectionString As String = "dsn=MyDatabase"
Dim sSQL As String = ""
Dim DBConnection As New OdbcConnection(sConnectionString)

Dim dsMaster As New DataSet
Dim daMaster As New OdbcDataAdapter
Dim dtMaster As New DataTable

Try

    DBConnection.Open()

    sSQL = "SELECT * FROM myTable"
    daMaster.SelectCommand = New OdbcCommand(sSQL, DBConnection)
    daMaster.Fill(dsMaster)

    If dsMaster.Tables(0).Rows.Count <> 0 Then
        dtMaster = dsMaster.Tables(0)

        sItem1 = dtMaster.Rows(0).Item(0).ToString
        sItem2 = dtMaster.Rows(0).Item(1).ToString
        sItem3 = dtMaster.Rows(0).Item(2).ToString
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No Records Available", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    End If
```

I removed the "MasterDataSet" parameter value from `daMaster.Fill()` because adding it would leave `dsMaster.Tables(0)` empty and put all your query data in `dsMaster.Tables("MasterDataSet")`.

Looks like this is most likely where your error was coming from.
Also you don't really need `dtMaster` because the data is already in a DataTable (dsMaster.Tables(0)) when you fill it.

So you would just reference those columns the same way:

```
sItem1 = dsMaster.Tables(0).Rows(0)(0).ToString
```

Keep in mind that providing the column names make it easier to read the code. So if you have the following query:

```
Dim sSQL As String = "SELECT Username, UserMail FROM Users WHERE UserID = 3"
```

Getting that data would look like this:

```
sItem1 = dsMaster.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Username")
```

You don't specifically need the `.ToString` added there, but if you don't get the data you expect, then add it in rather.